# How do I list entries by the same author on the single entry page?

Tags: author

I have a simple news site and on a single entry page where a news item is located I would like to list 3 or 4 other entries by the same author in the sidebar sorted by date.

I have one channel entries tag for the article text and another with the same channel but with an author_id parameter.

There are two problems I'm having, one is getting the author id from the url (I do not want to add another url segment just for this) and the second is making sure that it doesn't list the same entry that's currently being displayed on the page.

I would post my current code but it's all very standard stuff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're not using stash, you can simply use an embed *within your main channel entries tag* and pass the embed the author_id of the current author and the entry_id of the article being displayed:

```
{embed="sidebar/authorlist" author_id="{author_id}" entry_id="{entry_id}"}
```

and in your embed:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="..." dynamic="no" author_id="{embed:author_id}" entry_id="NOT {embed:entry_id}"}
```

Because it's a single entry page (limit="1") your embed will only be included once - but it means that your sidebar area in your template needs to be within the {exp:channel:entries} loop

Comment: aaah ok I didn't know it was possible to add a channel entries tag within another entries tag...I guess it doesn't work if it's not in an embed though...thanks a bunch, this will help me out for sure...I just started using stash too but I'll check out the documentation first before asking any other questions, cheers! :)

Comment: any chance you could tell me how this same thing could be done with stash?